# Separate sorting of all files in a directory

Tags: sorting, text, for-loop, cygwin

I am trying to sort sequentially the files in `input_directory` to `output_directory`.

I know how to do this for a single file as follows:

```
sort filename > newfilename
```

But, what I'd like the program to do is for every file in `input_directory` the following:

```
sort file_in_directrory > output_file_in_directory
```

How can I do that?

I am using cygwin sort.

Answer (score 1):

Use a `for` loop:

```
 for file in $(ls /PATH/TO/INPUT/DIR); 
 do 
   sort /PATH/TO/INPUT/DIR/$file > /PATH/TO/OUTPUT/DIR/$file; 
 done
```

Note that if any of the files in the input directory is a directory then `sort` command will fail as sort expects a file as input.

Comment: Thanks a lot! It almost worked. Except I had to modify as follows:  for file in $(ls /PATH/TO/INPUT/DIR/); 
 do 
   sort /PATH/TO/INPUT/DIR/$file > /PATH/TO/OUTPUT/DIR/$file; 
 done

Comment: I have a related question as well. I think it is pretty simple, I'd be extremely content if you could help me in that one as well.. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13078900/bash-script-iterative-merge-files-on-a-directory