# bash script - iterative merge files on a directory

Tags: bash, merge, cygwin

Hello I want to iteratively merge the files in input_directory and put the merged ones in output_directory.

Suppose in input_directory I have : file1.txt, file2.txt, file3.txt

I want to the output directory to contain the following files:

- merge1.txt : same as file1.txt
- merge2.txt : merge file1.txt file2.txt
- merge3.txt : merge file1.txt file2.txt file3.txt

I have almost no experience with bash scripts, it is obvious that it can be done with an iterator in a for loop, but I don't know how.

Thank you in advance..

Answer (score 0):

Store the previous filename that was appended to output and use it during next iteration:

```
#!/bin/bash

touch prev #a temp variable to hold previous filename
i=1;

for file in $(ls /INPUT/file*); 
do 
   cat /OUTPUT/$prev /INPUT/$file > /OUTPUT/merge$i;
   prev=merge$i;
   let i=i+1
 done
```

This code takes advantage of the fact `ls` list the files in sorted when they have same prefix. You can modify it if you have filenames with different prefixes and have a specific order in which you want to output them.

Comment: THANK YOU SO MUCH! I really appreciate it, you saved me hours! Thanks Thanks Thanks